# Excel vba if value is in column then

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a macro via an if then else function (maybe make use of a loop).

I have two separate files, named "orderregistratie" + "werkorder template".
I want to search in column A of sheets("datablad") in orderregistratie for the value sheets("export datablad").Range("A2") that is in werkorder template.

If this value exists in column A then copy the row of A2 from export datablad and paste it in the row where the value is found.
If it doesn't already exist I want to insert a new row at A2 in orderregistratie and copy the row of A2 from export datablad in the new row.

My VBA knowledge is not really good and I can't write the macro by myself. Is there anyone who can help me write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mischa Urlings for this example i have save both workbooks ("orderregistratie" + "werkorder template") on my desktop so you must change their path on the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim WbO As Workbook
    Dim WbW As Workbook

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LRA As Long
    Dim RowToCopy As Long
    Dim Rowstr As Long

    Dim Searchstr As String
    Dim Address As Range
    Dim Searchrng As Range

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\" & "orderregistratie.xlsx" '<= Open Workbooks (for this example files are stored on desktop
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\" & "werkorder template.xlsx"

    Set WbO = Workbooks("orderregistratie.xlsx") '<= Set workbook to variables
    Set WbW = Workbooks("werkorder template.xlsx")

    LRA = WbW.Worksheets("export datablad").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<= Find Lastrow

    For i = 2 To LRA '<= Loop column A (Workbook:werkorder template)
        Searchstr = WbW.Worksheets("export datablad").Range("A" & i).Value '<= Set what to search for
        Rowstr = i '<= Searchstr row
        Set Searchrng = WbO.Worksheets("datablad").Columns("A") '<= Set where to search for

        Set Address = Searchrng.Find(What:=Searchstr, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<= Result of the search

    If Address Is Nothing Then
        'If what we search for not found
        WbO.Worksheets("datablad").Rows("2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        WbW.Worksheets("export datablad").Rows(Rowstr).EntireRow.Copy
        WbO.Worksheets("datablad").Rows(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        'If what we search for found
        RowToCopy = Address.Row '<= Where we find the Searchstr
        WbW.Worksheets("export datablad").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        WbO.Worksheets("datablad").Rows(RowToCopy).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If



    Next i

    With WbO
       .Save
       .Close '<= Close open workbooks
    End with
    With WbW  
       .Save
       .Close '<= Close open workbooks
    End with 

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Error 1004, the macro doesn't exactly do what I want it to do. At first when the value is found, the values get pasted but when I select one of them I see a link to the other file. It just needs to be pasted as values in stead of keeping a link.  The other thing I see is that if the value isn't found, the line is pasted beneath the last row but I want it to past it in row 2 in stead of the last. I'll see if I can change it myself. Thanks for your quick help!!

Comment: @MischaUrlings i fix the part to add new lines in row 2 but i dont find any issues with link!

Comment: The data that is copied contains a link to another sheet of the same file. Example: A2 = 'Sheet!$C$6. I don't want this link to be copied but only the value. The insert row you added works perfectly!

Comment: @MischaUrlings glad to hear that the addition works perfectly.i review the code, check my testing documents but i dont find any links on then.Try to clean you sheets (by selectin whole sheets and delete, remove links and clear contents) Please try to investigate with debugging and if you need farther assistant let me know.

Comment: It isn't your fault or something but the problem is in my document. I think the type of copy you use in the macro copy's the value + formula behind the cells. Maybe it's possible to write entirerow.copy.value or something like that?

Comment: I m out of office now i ll check it tomorrow

Comment: @MischaUrlings also copy paste only values solved!see reviewed code!

Comment: works perfect, thank you very much! Could you have a look at my other post yesterday? Maybe you know a solution to it.

Comment: @MischaUrlings mention (write "@Error 1004" without " " as a comment) me at the post so i can look at it.

Comment: did you see my other question?

Comment: @Mischa Urlings tag me or send the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084488/excel-vba-pastespecial-xladd-loop/53085248?noredirect=1#comment93094052_53085248

Comment: Did you have a look at it?

Comment: Could you have a look at my new post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205534/excel-vba-if-2-criteria-then-else-function

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. I'll adjust as needed. Just be double check if both workbooks are saved to your desktop.

```vba
Option Explicit

Private wkbOrderReg     As Workbook, _
        wkbOrderWork    As Workbook, _
        wkb             As Workbook

Private wsOBJ           As Worksheet, _
        ws              As Worksheet

Private rngSearch       As Range, _
        rngRow          As Range, _
        rng             As Range, _
        r               As Range

Private strSearch       As String

Public Sub DarudeSandStorm()
    Dim LastRow     As Long, _
        LastColumn  As Long
    Dim arr         As Variant
    With Application.Workbooks
        Set wkbOrderReg = .Open(Filename:=strVar("orderregistratie.xlsx"))
        Set wkbOrderWork = .Open(Filename:=strVar("werkorder template.xlsx"))
    End With
    With wkbOrderWork
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            Set wsOBJ = ws
            If UCase$(wsOBJ.Name) = UCase$("export datablad") Then
                    With wsOBJ
                    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1))
                        strSearch = rng.Value
                        LastColumn = getLAST_COLUMN(wsOBJ)
                    Set rngRow = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, LastColumn))
                    End With
                        arr = rngRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
    With wkbOrderReg
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            Set wsOBJ = ws
            If UCase$(wsOBJ.Name) = UCase$("export datablad") Then
                With wsOBJ
                    LastRow = getLAST_ROW(wsOBJ)
                Set rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
                End With
                For Each r In rngSearch
                    If UCase$(r.Value) = UCase$(strSearch) Then
                        r = arr
                    End If
                Next r
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
    With Application
        For Each wkb In .Workbooks
            If Not wkb = .ThisWorkbook Then
                With .Workbooks(wkb.Name)
                    .Save
                    .Close
                End With
            End If
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub

Private Function getLAST_COLUMN(objWS As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim wsDES               As Worksheet, _
        wkbSUB              As Workbook, _
        rngCHECK            As Range
    Set rngCHECK = objWS.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rngCHECK Is Nothing Then
        getLAST_COLUMN = objWS.Cells.Find("*", _
                    Range("A1"), _
                    xlFormulas, _
                    , _
                    xlByColumns, _
                    xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        getLAST_COLUMN = 1
    End If
End Function

Private Function getLAST_ROW(objWS As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim wsDES               As Worksheet, _
        wkbSUB              As Workbook, _
        rngCHECK            As Range
    Set rngCHECK = objWS.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rngCHECK Is Nothing Then
        getLAST_ROW = objWS.Cells.Find("*", _
                    Range("A1"), _
                    xlFormulas, _
                    , _
                    xlByRows, _
                    xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        getLAST_ROW = 1
    End If
End Function

Private Function strVar(ByRef str As String) As String
    strVar = Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & str
End Function
```