# Excel vba PasteSpecial xlAdd loop

Tags: excel

I need some help with a PasteSpecial that i want to use.
    I made the following code myself:

```
    Sub oefen()

    ' oefen Macro
    Dim f As Long
    Dim d As Long
    d = Sheets("Omreken").Range("N2").Value
    f = Sheets("Omreken").Range("U2").Value

    For f = 1 To f + 1
    Range("O2").Copy
    Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next f

       For f = 2 To f - 1
       Range("T2").Copy
    Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
      Next f
      End Sub
```

My code does the following: 
Select a specific range which is adapted because of the loop. Everytime the loop is going through it adds the value of T2 to the original value of O2 that is pasted before I execute the xlAdd. The code almost works perfect for me, except I want to add +1 to T2 everytime the loop is going through.

So let's say i have A1 is 1, A2 is 1, A3 is 1, A4 is 1.
xlAdd; T2 is 1
If I am going through the loop i want the code to:

```
loop 1: A1 + T2*1 is 2
Loop 2: A2 + T2*2 is 3
Loop 3: A3 + T2*3 is 4
Loop 4: A4 + T2*4 is 5
```

I'm sorry for my English, I hope you understand what I'm trying to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this....I add a counter to the last loop and it will replace your value in `T2`.

```
Sub oefen()

    ' oefen Macro
    Dim f As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Static counter As Long
    d = Sheets("Omreken").Range("N2").Value
    f = Sheets("Omreken").Range("U2").Value
    counter = 1


    For f = 1 To f + 1
        Range("O2").Copy
        Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                               :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next f

    For f = 2 To f - 0
        Dim T2 As Long
        If Not f = 2 Then
            T2 = Cells(2, 20).Value
            T2 = T2 + counter
            Cells(2, 20).Value = T2
            Range("T2").Copy
            Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).Offset(-d, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks _
                                   :=False, Transpose:=False
        Else                                     'Skip counter for the first loop
            Range("T2").Copy
            Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).Offset(-d, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks _
                                   :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: The solution works almost perfect, made a small change and it works! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to paste the value to add it. You can simply calculate and set the value this way

```
Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).value = Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).value+Range("T2").value*(f-1)
```

If you cycle using `f` and it starts at 2 you need to add

```
Range("T2").value*(f-1)
```

to each value. So to first value it will add
T2*(2-1)=T2*1, to second it will add T2*2 and so on as you wanted

**Edit**:
when you receive error like type mismatch, what I do is generally check why it is happening when I am expecting to be summing up only numbers. You can do that by showing the values in messagebox (there are other nicer ways like debug - more info [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/) under point #4 or using breakpoints also in the link, but messagebox is simple). So currently if the line gives you error simply put this just before that line:

```
msgbox(Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).value)
msgbox(Range("T2").value)
```

Only be aware that it will show 2 popups per run of the cycle so limit your range. Run it this way and tell me what it shows before you get the type mismatch error.

EDIT 2:

```
Sub oefen()

    ' oefen Macro
    Dim f As Long
    Dim d As Long
    d = Sheets("Omreken").Range("N2").Value
    f = Sheets("Omreken").Range("U2").Value

    For f = 1 To f + 1
        Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).value=Range("O2").value
    Next f

    For f = 2 To f - 1
         Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f * d))).value =Range("A" & (2 + ((f - 1) * d)) & ":" & "A" & (1 + (f *d))).value+Range("T2").value*(f-1)
    Next f
  End Sub
```

note that I didnt change anything inside the Range row calculation or in the for cycles. you need to make sure those make sense as I dont know what values you have in `d` and `f`.

Comment: When I run the macro I get an error 13 during execution: types don't match

Comment: try to use msgbox to show you what is in the cells it is trying to add. Because I didnt do anything else than what you already have there so I am quite surprised

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're traying to say. Could you adapt this change to my code? Then I can see what needs to be changed. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Error 1004 This is the problem I"m having

Comment: can you update your question with printscreen of your current code and show  what line gives the error? Because Error 1004 is supposed to be error from selection or copy/paste, but my line of code does not select or copy/paste. Are you sure that the combination of f and d variables does not end in Range("A0") ?

Comment: I didn't mean that I got an error code in my macro, but I asked the person "Error 1004" on this website if he could help me with this new problem. So that's why I tagged him. Coming back to my question to you yesterday; could you adapt this change of the code you were saying?

Comment: Because the question is a bit 
confusing, please provide images of the original sheet and the desire output.

Comment: Just noticed that you are not adding, but replacing in the first part concerning O2 so I changed that in my code. Also yes, the original sheet and the desired output would help to uderstand, but either way using select and paste special xlAdd to add values is quite inefficient way to do it, so whatever the current issue is I would stick to using the .value method.